# SSRS: How to change value to negative in matrix based on column value

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a matrix in SSRS which looks something like this:

```
Account     DR/CR     Amount
(acc_num)   (drcr)    (sum(amount)) = expression below
            Total     (sum(amount))
```

it returns this table

```
Account     DR/CR       Amount

123456789   CR          5000
            DR          1000
            Total       6000

987654321   CR          3000
            DR          2000
            Total       5000
```

Table should provide total amount for Credit and Debit items for specific account. Column DR/CR represents whether the item is credit or debit. I need to change DR amount to negative sign so it will be 5000-1000=4000 for account 123456789

I used expression for this in column Amount and first row in matrix:

```
=IIf((Fields!drcr.Value)="DR",(Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)*(-1)),Sum(Fields!Amount.Value))
```

This did not work and basically DR amount stayed the same

expected result

```
Account     DR/CR       Amount

123456789   CR          5000
            DR         -1000
            Total       4000

987654321   CR          3000
            DR         -2000
            Total       1000
```

Thank you

edit1: ok I realized that this is not a good way to do it. Matrix consists of data from sourcedata and totals are calculating from source data too, so changing +/- in matrix doesn't change totals

edit2: I changed expression in source data and matrix doesn't reflect the change for some reason. So I guess I run out of options. What do you think?

I also tried expression for totals:

```
=SUM((iif(Fields!DRCR.Value = CR, Sum(Fields!AmountLocal.Value),0))),(iif(Fields!DRCR.Value = DR, Sum((Fields!AmountLocal.Value)*(-1)),0))
```

returned end of statement missing error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you did most of the work on this answer for us.  Yes, you are correct -- changing the value of the CR column doesn't change the value coming from the dataset so you do need to use an expression in the totals row.  Looks like you may just have some misplaced or unnecessary parenthesis in that last expression.  Try the following expression.

```
=SUM(iif(Fields!DRCR.Value = CR, Sum(Fields!AmountLocal.Value),0),(iif(Fields!DRCR.Value = DR, Sum((Fields!AmountLocal.Value)*(-1)),0)))
```

You had an unnecessary set of parenthesis around the `CR` IIF statement and the outermost `SUM` was being closed after that same IIF when it needed to be at the end.

I also want to recommend a tool like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) that has syntax highlighting.  Basically, you highlight each parenthesis and you can easily see where it is matching up and address any issues on complex expressions like this one.

Comment: thank for your reply. This also returned an error for some reason but eventually I tried different approach and changed my sql code by adding new columns cr and dt amounts so in totals I just made simple subtraction. thx anyway